# How to create an unorganised grid view in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, gridview, react-native-flatlist, ui-design

I am working on a React Native project in which I need to create an unorganized grid view. Please refer to the image.

[image: the multi selection <code>grid view</code>]

I have no idea how to achieve this type of view dynamically with the below `JSON` data.

```
categories: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Tolerance'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Equality'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Empowerment'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'LGBTQ+'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Equal opportunity'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Success stories'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        title: 'News'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        title: 'Inclusivity'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        title: 'People'
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        title: 'Jobs'
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        title: 'Consciousness'
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        title: 'Responsibility'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        title: 'Diversity'
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        title: 'Networking'
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        title: 'Lifestyle'
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        title: 'Pride'
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        title: 'Economy'
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        title: 'Climate'
    }
]
```

Right now I am using separate `TextView` with the separate clicks manually. I need to make it dynamically as I am getting this list from the server.

My concern is that, is it possible to make this type of view or do I need to continue working on the approach on which I am working right now?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get the data from the server and store it in Redux.
After that get your data into the component, map it and create a layout with Flexbox.